# Change current today date in Fullcalendar V5 not working

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using fullcalendar for my web application. I am not using npm, webpack or something else, I just include the needed files by [javascript tags](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals).
I used to set a custom today date (different from real today) using "now" option. But now I
upgraded from v4 to v5 and for some reason I am not able to change the "today" date nor the "now" indicator anymore.

My implementation is something like:

`myFullCalendar.setOption("now", new Date(2021, 03, 22, 14, 00))`

which correctly works on v4 but it doesn't on v5.

If I try to print the option with:

`console.log( myFullCalendar.getOption("now") )`

I see that the value has been correctly set but the highlight and the now indicator position doesn't change.

What am I missing? I took a look to the [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/now) but I did not find a solution, also there is no clear example on how to do it, is it a bug or should I set something else on v5 ?

Any help would be very appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you re-render the calendar afterwards, otherwise you won't see anything change:

```
myFullCalendar.setOption("now", new Date(2021, 03, 22, 14, 00));
myFullCalendar.render();
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/NWpbwda

Comment: Ok I checked on codepen but It seems working only once.. I mean, if you try to do more then one set, only the first seems to be took into account.. Is it not possibile anymore to change the current date after init and render calls?

Comment: Hm, you seem to be correct. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/oNZYpgY. Not sure if that's a bug or intentional - you should raise it with the maintainers of fullCalendar. Details here: https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs

Comment: That's the point.. I don't understand if It Is intentional.. if so, it's a bit limiting and not backward compatible..

Comment: Well I can't help you with whether it's intentional or not. That's why you need to raise a bug and find out.